# recargar src de audio con jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

Lo que quiero hacer es un juego de adivinar la cancion, son de series de tv. Lo tengo hecho de la manera siguiente:

-El usuario entra y en el body he puesto la etiqueta de HTML5:

```html
<audio controls> 
  <source src="audios/XXXX.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="reproductor"> 
</audio>
```

- En un jQuery revisa el titulo de la cancion y lo escrito por el usuario, si concide, añade un punto al marcador (ahora sale un alert solo)
- El usuario tiene una flecha que al hacer click lo que hace es enviar un jQuery que cambia el valor del src del source por otro (mediante Array), es aqui donde falla.

Si inspecciono el codigo veo que efectivamente el src del audio ha cambiado perfectamente, y si escribo el actual valor de este, me lo da correcto. Sin embargo el usuario en el reproductor sigue escuchando la 1a cancion...

¿Que puedo hacer para que el usuario escuche la cancion "dinamicamente"?
¿Se puede hacer tirando de jQuery o hay que meterse con... PHP?

-- HTML --

```
   <div class="audio">
        <audio controls>
          <source src="audios/hospital central.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="reproductor">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="respuesta">
        <form action="#" id="form">
            <input type="text" id="respuesta"> <br />
            <button id="btn-resp">RESPONDER</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

// script jquery antes del body

```js
        function rand(n){
        // creamos un numero al azar entre 1 y 10 (o cual sea la cantidad de imágenes)
         return(Math.floor(Math.random() * n + 1 ));
        }
 
        //guardamos los audios en el array
        var cambia_audio = new Array();
        cambia_audio[0] = "audios/equipo a.mp3";
        cambia_audio[1] = "audios/padre de familia.mp3";
        cambia_audio[2] = "audios/hawaii 5-0.mp3";
        cambia_audio[3] = "audios/el coche fantastico.mp3";
        cambia_audio[4] = "audios/hospital central.mp3";
        cambia_audio[5] = "audios/medico de familia.mp3";
        cambia_audio[6] = "audios/los vigilantes de la playa.mp3";
        cambia_audio[7] = "audios/oliver y benji.mp3";
        cambia_audio[8] = "audios/el principe de bel air.mp3";
        cambia_audio[9] = "audios/friends.mp3";
 
        function cambiar(){
            document.getElementById("reproductor").src = cambia_audio[rand(10)-1];
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EL BOTON SIGUIENTE :

```js
$('#btn-resp').click(function(){
        var respuesta = $('#respuesta').val();
        //var correcta = "";
        var aciertos_box = $('#aciertos').val();
        var nombre_cancion = $("#reproductor").attr("src");
        var contadorAciertos = 0;
        var contadorFallos = 0;
 
        var respuesta = 'audios/'+respuesta+'.mp3'; // Montamos estructura de carpeta y extension 
 
 
        if(respuesta == nombre_cancion) {
            alert("acerto");
            contadorAciertos++;
            $("#aciertos").html(contadorAciertos);
        }
        else{
            alert("fallo");
            contadorFallos++;
            $("#fallos").html(contadorFallos);
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: has probado a reproducir tras cambiar el `src`?
  ej: `$("#reproductor").attr("src",cambia_audio[rand(10)-1]).trigger("play");` (en tu codigo no se ve cuando llamas a `Cambiar()`)

Comment: A parte de lo indicado por @lois6b te diría que pusieras el script después del body, para que cargue primero el código html